# How to render video stream through html - Socketio

Tags: node.js, html, socket.io

I don't want to use WebRTC since my client does not want it. I just want to stream video. I have managed to transmit the buffer through https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream. But, I am not sure how to render it in video tag of html. Please help!

Reference: [How to Stream audio/video with socket (.io) from node.js server to html5 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822821/how-to-stream-audio-video-with-socket-io-from-node-js-server-to-html5-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [socket.io-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-stream)

Comment: I cannot render the data received in socket-io-stream in HTML video tag. As I had already attached the reference link, it appears that several people are struggling with the same. Do you have any idea on how to achieve this?